# How to get server time and update every second?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, date

I am making ajax request to a particular server and getting the response also. I am doing cross domain request so using jsonp. Is there a way to get the server time to which i am making the request. Will it be better to write `php script` or doing just ajax request is good. Suppose if i make the following request :

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: 'jsonp=date',
        jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',                
        url: 'http://www.google.com',   
        success: function (data) {                  
        }
});
```

How can i get the server time from this request? Please help if any suggestion. Also after getting the time if i use `setInterval` method to update time every second will it be a costly operation or better to make the same ajax request after a particular time to update time. I have real time data to update with the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the server's time if it doesn't explicitly provide it to you.
You can read its HTTP headers, but that's not a good thing since the headers may not provide this information every time, or their format may not be the same all the time.

Also, I don't see the point of asking it every second.
Ask it one single time, calculate the difference between its time and yours, and here you go: you got the difference of time and you can use it wherever you want.

Keep in mind that even if you get the time, there probably will be a difference between the one you got and the server's real time because of the network's latency.

Comment: The server i am making request is currently using UTC time. So i want to take this time and then convert according to the client's timezone

Comment: HTTP headers aren't available on a jsonp since no XHR object is used.

Comment: @JonathanM Thanks for pointing that out. Feel free to edit my answer. :)

Comment: @Sammy, no edit necessary. Good answer regarding getting the time once and considering latency.

Comment: @user850234 If you already know the server timezone, simply use PHP to convert your local date to that timezone time!

Comment: @SamyDindane : Is it not possible to get the timezone and time of the server using php in any way and then do the reverse way. Currently i know the timezone of the server but i want to always detect the server timezone and time and then do the convertion according to the local system timezone. Is this possible in any way around?

Comment: @user850234 If you know the server's timezone and your local one, you can convert the time from one to the other easily. Some resources on the Internet will explain it better than me, in a comment. Also, make sure *date.timezone* is correctly set on your server. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to part 1 is that you will need to output the server time in the response in order for your javascript to read it. For part 2, I would wait for the response to load, and then use `setTimeout`. Using `setInterval` means that you might fire the ajax call twice before the first response returns.

Answer (score 0):

When you suggest server time do you mean the script that is executing the call or the actual time on the server?

What is the need for this, are you trying to figure out time between calls to automate calls every 5 secs for example?

If you are then just simply getting a locale time from javascript and comparing that from when you get a response in ajax would suffice?

Otherwise javascript isn't going to be able to get server time, due to its 'clientside' nature.